# Using 'find' to return filenames without extension

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I have a directory (with subdirectories), of which I want to find all files that have a ".ipynb" extension. But I want the 'find' command to just return me these filenames without the extension.

I know the first part:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.ipynb" -print
```

But how do I then get the names without the "ipynb" extension?
Any replies greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To return only filenames without the extension, try:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.ipynb" -execdir sh -c 'printf "%s\n" "${0%.*}"' {} ';'
```

or *(omitting `-type f` from now on)*:

```
find "$PWD" -iname "*.ipynb" -execdir basename {} .ipynb ';'
```

or:

```
find . -iname "*.ipynb" -exec basename {} .ipynb ';'
```

or:

```
find . -iname "*.ipynb" | sed "s/.*\///; s/\.ipynb//"
```

however invoking `basename` on each file can be inefficient, so [@CharlesDuffy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41965415/using-find-to-return-filenames-without-extension/41965460?noredirect=1#comment77844258_41965460) suggestion is:

```
find . -iname '*.ipynb' -exec bash -c 'printf "%s\n" "${@%.*}"' _ {} +
```

or:

```
find . -iname '*.ipynb' -execdir basename -s '.sh' {} +
```

<sup>Using [`+` means](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/195939/21471) that we're passing multiple files to each bash instance, so if the whole list fits into a single command line, we call bash only once.</sup>

---

To print full path and filename (without extension) in the same line, try:

```
find . -iname "*.ipynb" -exec sh -c 'printf "%s\n" "${0%.*}"' {} ';'
```

or:

```
find "$PWD" -iname "*.ipynb" -print | grep -o "[^\.]\+"
```

---

To print full path and filename on separate lines:

```
find "$PWD" -iname "*.ipynb" -exec dirname "{}" ';' -exec basename "{}" .ipynb ';'
```

Comment: Applying `basename` would also throw away the directory component.

Comment: I believe this is what is asked for, list only filenames without extension.

Comment: Executing `basename` once per file seems rather inefficient. `find . -name '*.ipynb' -exec bash -c 'printf "%s\n" "${@%.*}"' _ {} +` would just invoke one shell per batch of files, so considerably less overhead.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Added into the list. Wouldn't invoking bash on each file be inefficient as well? Or it's executed on all files because of `+`?

Comment: @kenorb, the `+` means we're passing multiple files to each bash instance -- if the whole list fits into a single command line, we call bash only once.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy What happens if the whole list cannot fit into a single command?

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan, ...in that case, `-exec ... {} +` runs the command multiple times (each with a subset of the file list), just as `xargs` does.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a simple solution:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.ipynb" | sed 's/\.ipynb$//1'
```

Comment: There's no need for the `/1`, as the pattern cannot match more than once (assuming no embedded newlines in filenames).

Comment: I used this one since it doesn't fork a process like bash or basename for each file.  A bit custom, but faster.

Answer (score 5):

I found this in a bash oneliner that simplifies the process without using find

```
for n in *.ipynb; do echo "${n%.ipynb}"; done
```

Comment: This only works if the files are in the current directory. The OP's original code can find files in subdirectories.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have the name with directory but without the extension :

```
find .  -type f -iname "*.ipynb" -exec sh -c 'f=$(basename $1 .ipynb);d=$(dirname $1);echo "$d/$f"' sh {} \;
```

Comment: It would be more correct to quote your expansions: `f=$(basename "$1" .ipynb);d=$(dirname "$1"); echo "$d/$f"` -- that way filenames with whitespace or glob characters are less prone to being problematic.

Comment: That said, this is pretty inefficient right now -- for each file, you're starting a new copy of `sh`, having at spawn a subshell and run the non-builtin program `/bin/basename` within it, and then another subshell invoking `/bin/dirname`. Using `-exec ... {} +` would let you share a single copy of `sh` across multiple filenames (though you'd need to iterate over them instead of hardcoding `$1`); even better would be to stream all your names through a single subprocess that does the work, with _no_ new per-name subprocesses being started at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -iname "*.ipynb" | grep -oP '.*(?=[.])'
```

The -o flag outputs only the matched part. The -P flag matches according to Perl regular expressions. This is necessary to make the [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=[.])` work.

Answer (score 0):

**Perl One Liner**
*what you want*
`find . | perl -a -F/ -lne 'print $F[-1] if /.*.ipynb/g'`

**Then not your code**
*what you do not want*
`find . | perl -a -F/ -lne 'print $F[-1] if !/.*.ipynb/g'`

**NOTE**
In **Perl** you need to put extra `.`. So your pattern would be `.*.ipynb`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know that the extension is or there are multiple you could use this:

```
find . -type f -exec basename {} \;|perl -pe 's/(.*)\..*$/$1/;s{^.*/}{}'
```

and for a list of files with no duplicates (originally differing in path or extension)

```
find . -type f -exec basename {} \;|perl -pe 's/(.*)\..*$/$1/;s{^.*/}{}'|sort|uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way which uses `basename` is:

```
find . -type f -iname '*.ipynb' -exec basename -s '.ipynb' {} +
```

Using `+` will reduce the number of invocations of the command ([manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html)):

> -exec command {} +
>
> This variant of the -exec action runs the specified command on
>   the selected files, but the command line is built by appending
>   each selected file name at the end; the total number of
>   invocations of the command will be much less than the number
>   of matched files.  The command line is built in much the same
>   way that xargs builds its command lines.  Only one instance of
>   '{}' is allowed within the command, and (when find is being
>   invoked from a shell) it should be quoted (for example, '{}')
>   to protect it from interpretation by shells.  The command is
>   executed in the starting directory.  If any invocation with
>   the `+' form returns a non-zero value as exit status, then
>   find returns a non-zero exit status.  If find encounters an
>   error, this can sometimes cause an immediate exit, so some
>   pending commands may not be run at all.  For this reason -exec
>   my-command ... {} + -quit may not result in my-command
>   actually being run.  This variant of -exec always returns
>   true.

Using `-s` with `basename` runs accepts multiple filenames and removes a specified suffix ([manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/basename.1.html)):

> -a, --multiple
>
> support multiple arguments and treat each as a NAME
>
> -s, --suffix=SUFFIX
>
> remove a trailing SUFFIX; implies -a

Answer (score -1):

If there's no occurrence of this ".ipynb" string on any file name other than a suffix, then you can try this simpler way using `tr`:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.ipynb" -print | tr -d ".ipbyn"
```

Comment: Simplest answer most useful most of the time.

Comment: This is a bad answer because `tr` doesn't care of the characters are in order, it will delete all occurrences of any single of those characters. Example: `echo snipsnap | tr -d ".ipbyn"` => `ssa`