# Passing filename as variable from find's exec into a second exec command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

From reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41965415/using-find-to-return-filenames-without-extension) stackoverflow answer I was able to remove the file extension from the files using find:

```
find . -name "S4*" -execdir basename {} .fastq.gz ';'
```

returned:

```
S9_S34_R1_001
S9_S34_R2_001
```

I'm making a batch script where I want to extract the filename with the above prefix to pass as arguments into a program. At the moment I'm currently doing this with a loop but am wondering if it can be achieved using find.

```
for i in $(ls | grep 'S9_S34*' | cut -d '.' -f 1); do echo "$i"_trim.log "$i"_R1_001.fastq.gz "$i"_R2_001.fastq.gz; done; >> trim_script.sh
```

Is it possible to do something as follows:

```
find . -name "S4*" -execdir basename {} .fastq.gz ';' | echo {}_trim.log {}_R1_001.fastq.gz {}_R2_001.fastq.gz {}\ ; >> trim_script.sh
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `basename` at all, *or* `-exec`, if all you're doing is generating a series of strings that contain your file's basenames within them; the `-printf` action included in GNU `find` can do all that for you, as it provides a `%P` built-in to insert the basename of your file:

```
find . -name "S4*" \
  -printf '%P_trim.log %P_R1_001.fastq.gz %P_R2_001.fastq.gz %P\n' \
  >trim_script.sh
```

That said, be sure you only do this if you trust your filenames. If you're truly running the result as a script, there are serious security concerns if someone could create a `S4$(rm -rf ~).txt` file, or something with a similarly malicious name.

---

What if you don't trust your filenames, or don't have the GNU version of `find`? Then consider making `find` pass them into a shell (like bash or ksh) that supports the `%q` extension, to generate a safely-escaped version of those names (note that you should run the script with the same interpreter you used for this escaping):

```
find . -name "S4*" -exec bash -c '
  for file do        # iterates over "$@", so processes each file in turn
    file=${file##*/} # get the basename
    printf "%q_trim.log %q_R1_001.fastq.gz %q_R2_001.fastq.gz %q\n" \
     "$file" "$file" "$file" "$file"
  done
' _ {} + >trim_script.sh
```

Using `-exec ... {} +` invokes the smallest possible number of subprocesses -- not one per file found, but instead one per batch of filenames (using the largest possible batch that can fit on a command line).

Comment: Actually this doesn't solve my problem. When I run the first code I get the whole filename prefix and extension concatenated onto the variables so I end up with S9_S34_R1_001.fastq.gz_R2_001.fastq.gz whereas I just need to extract S9_S34 or S9_S34_R1_001. Appreciate your response anyway!

Comment: In that case, go with the second approach and add `file=${file%%.*}` (to strip the extensions) as an additional command after the `file=${file##*/}` (which strips the directory name elements). Two parameter expansions is several orders of magnitude faster than a single `fork()`/`exec()` pair, so you're still coming out ahead.