# find files based on extension but display name without extension no basename, sed, awk, grep or ; allowed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I need to write a script that lists all the files with a .gif extension in the current directory and all its sub-directories BUT DO NOT use ANY of:

- basename
- grep
- egrep
- fgrep
- rgrep
- &&
- ||
- ;
- sed
- awk

AND still include hidden files.

I tried `find . -type f -name '*.gif' -printf '%f\n'` which will succesfully display .gif files, but still shows extension. Here's the catch: if I try to use `cut -d . -f 1` to remove file extension, I also remove hidden files (which I don't want to) because their names start with ".".

Then I turned to use `tr -d '.gif'` but some of the files have a 'g' or a '.' in their name.

I also tried to use some of [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41965415/using-find-to-return-filenames-without-extension) BUT all of them include either basename, sed, awk or use some ";" in their script.

With so many restrictions I really don't know if it's even possible to achieve that but I'm supposed to.

How would you do it?

Comment: I'm not allowed to use the ";" character in my script

Comment: Why are you not allowed to use `;` ? looks odd requirement. Is it homework ?

Comment: `tr` is completely wrong; your command will remove all occurrences of `.` or `g` or `i` or `f`

Comment: Please review [homework guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### files/dirs structure:

```
$ tree -a
.
├── bar
├── bar.gif
├── base
│   └── foo.gif
├── foo
│   └── aaa.gif
└── .qux.gif

3 directories, 4 files
```

##### Code

```
find -type f -name '*.gif' -exec bash -c 'printf "%s\n" "${@%.gif}"' bash {} +
```

##### Output

```
./bar
./.qux
./foo/aaa
./base/foo
```

##### Explanations

*Parameter Expansion* expands parameters: `$foo`, `$1`. You can use it to perform string or array operations: `"${file%.mp3}"`, `"${0##*/}"`, `"${files[@]: -4}"`. They should **always** be quoted. See: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073 and "Parameter Expansion" in man bash. Also see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe.

Comment: The thing is, the for loop has a ";" in it, and I'm not allowed to use that character in my script. I forgot to mention the script should be one line long.

Comment: Code edited accordingly

Comment: Using `+` instead of `;` is kind of cheating I guess; but the question is so bad it probably deserves it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
find . -name '*.gif' -type f -execdir bash -c 'printf "%s\n" "${@%.*}"' bash {} +
```

Comment: I read that it's best to avoid using anything other than "bash" as a placeholder (`_` here). It's about error handling

Comment: Then `bash` it is! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
perl -MFile::Find::Rule -E '
    say s/\.gif$//r for File::Find::Rule
        ->file()
        ->name(qr/\.gif\z/)
        ->in(".")
'
```

Output:

```
bar
.qux
foo/aaa
base/foo
```